How to close one sidebar if the other is open?
I'm having an issue with my sidebars. I have two sidebars - one for filters and the other for the cart. When I open the cart sidebar, it automatically closes the filters sidebar. However, when I open the filters sidebar again, the cart sidebar stays open. How can I modify my JavaScript code to close one sidebar when the other is open? I have one sidebar <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar"> and other is <div class="cart"> I also have a script in html code for closing navbar
 <script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";

        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";

        }
    </script>

let iconCart = document.querySelector('.iconCart');
let cart = document.querySelector('.cart');
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let close = document.querySelector('.close');
let sidebarFilters = document.getElementById('mySidebar');

iconCart.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (cart.style.right == '-100%') {
        cart.style.right = '0';
        container.style.transform = 'translateX(-400px)';
        closeSidebar(sidebarFilters);
    } else {
        cart.style.right = '-100%';
        container.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    }
});

close.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cart.style.right = '-100%';
    container.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
});

function closeSidebar(sidebar) {
    sidebar.style.width = "0";
}


let products = null;
// Fetch data from JSON file
fetch('product.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        products = data;
        addDataToHTML(products);
        addDataToHTML1(products);
        setupFilters(products);
        setupSearch(products); // Setup search functionality
    });

// Show product data in the list
function addDataToHTML(products) {
    let listProductHTML = document.querySelector('.listProduct');
    listProductHTML.innerHTML = '';

    if (products != null) {
        products.forEach(product => {
            let newProduct = document.createElement('div');
            newProduct.classList.add('item');
            newProduct.innerHTML =
                `<img src="${product.image}" alt="">
                <h2>${product.name}</h2>
                <div class="price">${product.price}rsd</div>
                <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="redirectToDetailsPage(${product.id})">View Details</a><br>
                <button onclick="addCart(${product.id})">
                    <span class="spann">Add to cart</span>
                    <div class="cartt">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 36 26">
                            <polyline points="1 2.5 6 2.5 10 18.5 25.5 18.5 28.5 7.5 7.5 7.5"></polyline>
                            <polyline points="15 13.5 17 15.5 22 10.5"></polyline>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </button>`;

            listProductHTML.appendChild(newProduct);

            // Add event listener for the rotation animation
            let button = newProduct.querySelector('button');
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                button.classList.add('loading');
                // Remove the class after animation to allow re-triggering the animation on next click
                button.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
                    button.classList.remove('loading');
                }, { once: true });
            });
        });
    }
}

function addDataToHTML1(products) {
    let klimaProductHTML = document.querySelector('.klimaProduct');
    let pumpaProductHTML = document.querySelector('.pumpaProduct');
    let televizorProductHTML = document.querySelector('.televizorProduct');

    if (klimaProductHTML) klimaProductHTML.innerHTML = '';
    if (pumpaProductHTML) pumpaProductHTML.innerHTML = '';
    if (televizorProductHTML) televizorProductHTML.innerHTML = '';

    if (products != null) {
        products.forEach(product => {
            let newProduct = document.createElement('div');
            newProduct.classList.add('item');
            newProduct.innerHTML =
                `<img src="${product.image}" alt="">
                <h2>${product.name}</h2>
                <div class="price">${product.price}rsd</div>
                <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="redirectToDetailsPage(${product.id})">View Details</a><br>
                <button onclick="addCart(${product.id})">
                    <span class="spann">Add to cart</span>
                    <div class="cartt">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 36 26">
                            <polyline points="1 2.5 6 2.5 10 18.5 25.5 18.5 28.5 7.5 7.5 7.5"></polyline>
                            <polyline points="15 13.5 17 15.5 22 10.5"></polyline>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </button>`;

            switch (product.category) {
                case 'klima':
                    if (klimaProductHTML) klimaProductHTML.appendChild(newProduct);
                    break;
                case 'pumpa':
                    if (pumpaProductHTML) pumpaProductHTML.appendChild(newProduct);
                    break;
                case 'televizor':
                    if (televizorProductHTML) televizorProductHTML.appendChild(newProduct);
                    break;
            }

            // Add event listener for the rotation animation
            let button = newProduct.querySelector('button');
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                button.classList.add('loading');
                // Remove the class after animation to allow re-triggering the animation on next click
                button.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
                    button.classList.remove('loading');
                }, { once: true });
            });
        });
    }
}


function redirectToDetailsPage(productId) {
    window.location.href = `details.html?id=${productId}`;
}

// Use cookie so the cart doesn't get lost on refresh page
let listCart = [];

function checkCart() {
    var cookieValue = document.cookie
        .split('; ')
        .find(row => row.startsWith('listCart='));
    if (cookieValue) {
        listCart = JSON.parse(cookieValue.split('=')[1]);
    } else {
        listCart = [];
    }
}
checkCart();

function addCart($idProduct) {
    let productsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
    if (!listCart[$idProduct]) {
        listCart[$idProduct] = productsCopy.filter(product => product.id == $idProduct)[0];
        listCart[$idProduct].quantity = 1;
    } else {
        listCart[$idProduct].quantity++;
    }
    document.cookie = "listCart=" + JSON.stringify(listCart) + "; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2025 23:59:59 UTC; path=/;";
    addCartToHTML();
}
addCartToHTML();

function addCartToHTML() {
    let listCartHTML = document.querySelector('.listCart');
    listCartHTML.innerHTML = '';

    let totalHTML = document.querySelector('.totalQuantity');
    let totalQuantity = 0;

    if (listCart) {
        listCart.forEach(product => {
            if (product) {
                let newCart = document.createElement('div');
                newCart.classList.add('item');
                newCart.innerHTML =
                    `<img src="${product.image}">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="name">${product.name}</div>
                        <div class="price">${product.price}rsd / 1 product</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <button onclick="changeQuantity(${product.id}, '-')">-</button>
                        <span class="value">${product.quantity}</span>
                        <button onclick="changeQuantity(${product.id}, '+')">+</button>
                    </div>`;
                listCartHTML.appendChild(newCart);
                totalQuantity = totalQuantity + product.quantity;
            }
        });
    }
    totalHTML.innerText = totalQuantity;
}

function changeQuantity($idProduct, $type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case '+':
            listCart[$idProduct].quantity++;
            break;
        case '-':
            listCart[$idProduct].quantity--;
            if (listCart[$idProduct].quantity <= 0) {
                delete listCart[$idProduct];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    document.cookie = "listCart=" + JSON.stringify(listCart) + "; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2025 23:59:59 UTC; path=/;";
    addCartToHTML();
}

// Function to set up filters
function setupFilters(products) {
    const categoryCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id^="category-"]');
    const sizeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id^="size-"]');
    const colorCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id^="color-"]');

    function applyFilters() {
        const selectedCategories = Array.from(categoryCheckboxes)
            .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
            .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

        const selectedSizes = Array.from(sizeCheckboxes)
            .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
            .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

        const selectedColors = Array.from(colorCheckboxes)
            .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
            .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

        const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => {
            const categoryMatch = selectedCategories.length === 0 || selectedCategories.includes(product.category);
            const sizeMatch = selectedSizes.length === 0 || selectedSizes.includes(product.size);
            const colorMatch = selectedColors.length === 0 || selectedColors.includes(product.color);

            return categoryMatch && sizeMatch && colorMatch;
        });

        addDataToHTML(filteredProducts);
        addDataToHTML1(filteredProducts);
    }

    categoryCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener("change", applyFilters);
    });

    sizeCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener("change", applyFilters);
    });

    colorCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.addEventListener("change", applyFilters);
    });
}

// Function to set up search
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Funkcija za pretragu
    function searchProducts() {
        var input = document.getElementById("search-bar");
        var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
        var products = document.querySelectorAll('.klimaProduct .item, .listProduct .item');

        products.forEach(function(product) {
            var productName = product.querySelector('h2').innerText.toLowerCase();
            if (productName.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                product.style.display = "";
            } else {
                product.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    }

    // Dodavanje event listener-a na click događaj za dugme pretrage
    document.getElementById("search-btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Da bismo sprečili podrazumevanu akciju dugmeta
        searchProducts(); // Pozivamo funkciju za pretragu kada se klikne na dugme
    });

    // Onemogućavanje podrazumevane akcije pritiska tastera prilikom unosa u polje za pretragu
    document.getElementById("search-bar").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault(); // Da bismo sprečili podrazumevanu akciju pritiska tastera Enter
            searchProducts(); // Pozivamo funkciju za pretragu kada se pritisne taster Enter
        }
    });
});


//animacija za search

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-bar');

    searchButton.addEventListener('click', searchProducts);
    searchInput.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault();
            searchProducts();
        }
    });

    const observerOptions = {
        root: null, // koristi viewport kao root
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.1 // 10% elementa treba biti vidljivo
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, observerOptions);

    function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                entry.target.classList.add('visible');
                entry.target.classList.remove('fade-up');
            } else {
                entry.target.classList.remove('visible');
                entry.target.classList.add('fade-up');
            }
        });
    }

    function searchProducts() {
        const searchQuery = document.getElementById('search-bar').value.toLowerCase();
        const allProducts = document.querySelectorAll('.listProduct .item, .klimaProduct .item, .pumpaProduct .item, .televizorProduct .item');

        allProducts.forEach(product => {
            const productName = product.textContent.toLowerCase();
            if (productName.includes(searchQuery)) {
                product.classList.remove('hidden');
                product.classList.add('fade-up');
                if (!product.classList.contains('visible')) {
                    observer.observe(product); // Dodaj proizvod u observer samo ako nije već vidljiv
                }
            } else {
                product.classList.remove('visible');
                product.classList.add('hidden');
                observer.unobserve(product); // Ukloni proizvod iz observer-a
            }
        });
    }

    // Inicijalno dodaj sve proizvode u observer
    const allProducts = document.querySelectorAll('.listProduct .item, .klimaProduct .item, .pumpaProduct .item, .televizorProduct .item');
    allProducts.forEach(product => {
        if (!product.classList.contains('visible')) {
            observer.observe(product);
        }
    });
});


you should read into classList and toggle(). The mdoern approach is to use CSS classes instead of manipulating inline-style. Especially classList.toggle() makes the use of if/else for such cases completely unecessary.

Where's the jQuery? Please don't use tags for libraries you're not using.

Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] using a Stack Snippet so that answerers can more easily answer your question.

Please take the [tour] and see [ask], then make the requested revisions to your question post. Those weren't tips for next time. They're advice to keep your question from being closed by the community since it's difficult to answer with confidence.

Using the same logic, when opening the sidebar, close the cart (I'm trying to re-use the code for closing the cart with a function called closeCart)


// change this
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  closeCart()
}


function closeCart() {
  cart.style.right = '-100%';
  container.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
}

close.addEventListener('click', closeCart);



